# Configuration error after deploying asp.net files into iis server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis, deployment

I am getting the following error which deploying my code in the production server. Code is working fine in development.

```
    Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (E:\QA\form\web.config line 103)

Source Error: 


Line 101:       </httpHandlers>
Line 102:       <httpModules>
Line 103:           <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
Line 104:       </httpModules>
Line 105:   </system.web>


Source File: E:\QA\form\web.config    Line: 103 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

Please advice !

Answer (score 1):

The server doesn't have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is depending on the .Net 3.5 runtime, but your server only has .Net 2.0.

The [instructions here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/30/asp-net-ajax-in-net-3-5-and-vs-2008.aspx) will let you install the components you need on the server. You need at least the ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 download, which should run with .Net 2.0.